# How to collapse Standard Actions in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is collapsing Actions not supported in Lightning as it is in Classic by clicking on the Action's header name? Or is this something that can be enabled?

Clicking on this Email Action header name, for instance, does not collapse the Action as it previously did in Classic. Some of these Actions take up a large portion of the page, currently, the workaround is to simply refresh the page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. You could do this in Classic. There's no way to do this in Lightning as of right now.

Please upvote the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKcCQAU) to support it in Lightning.